# optimal view structure with Ember.js for a mobile application

Tags: ember.js

Lately I have been building a mobile phone application using Sproutcore20 and now Ember.JS.
This works great on my iPhone (3GS) though it stutters on many android devices.

The simplest thing, like switching from main menu item, and thus loading in a different view feels all but native.

Currently it makes use of template views which are appended and removed in a statechart. Each main menu item has a main state in which the corresponding views are appended (and removed on exit).

This method seems optimal to me but it does not function optimal, so I am wondering if an alternative approach like appending all views on load (deferred) and visibility toggling would improve performance (1)? It would make the DOM larger and thus operations on the DOM slower.

What is an optimal Ember.js code structure for building a mobile application, and what  considerations need to be taken into account when building for mobile devices(2)?

Comment: Please, only one question at once.

Comment: The second question is merely an explanation of the answer given to the first question, exactly same context and posting twice seems useless.

Comment: @ralf if it does seem useless to you then please look away. If you read the question carefully, you will see the second fold to the very question. I read it as what considerations need to be taken into account when building for mobile devices using Ember.js

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on your application. In general, limiting the number of DOM elements and the number of DOM changes helps performance. Deciding whether to leave elements in the DOM and hide/show them, or to create/destroy elements on demand depends on the usage patterns of the app. If you expect the user to move quickly back and forth between views, hide/show can make sense.